# SQL CASE between values of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have the following @temp table :

```
SELECT * 
FROM @temp
WHERE LinkingID = 1

------------------------------------------------------------------
|Condition_ID   LinkingID   Operator   Variable1    Variable2    |
|     1             1          ==        25             2        |
|     2             1          <>        3              7        |
|     3             1          ==        4              4        |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to implement a `CASE` ( ??? ) that will check if **Variable1** `OPERATOR` **Variable2** is true, make the check for all rows and IF all rows are true then do something, else break off and abort.

I was thinking something like this ( I'm not sure how to express this in T-SQL so I use pseudolanguage ) :

```
CASE 
    WHEN Operator LIKE '=='
        THEN IF Variable1 == Variable2 THEN TRUE
        ELSE THEN FALSE
    WHEN Operator LIKE '<>'
        THEN IF Variable1  <> Variable2 THEN TRUE
        ELSE THEN FALSE
FROM @temp
```

If the result of this is true for all rows, then do something, else do something else

In the scenario above :
Row1 would return `FALSE`
Row2 would return `TRUE`
Row3 would return `TRUE`

Hence the result is `FALSE`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Do you want to delete all rows where the condition `var1 operator var2` is true? It would be easier to do in 1 step rather than iterating over each row. SQL is set-based.

Comment: I thought I was implementing a row-by-row CASE, but now I realized CASE makes this iteration anyway. Do I not need a `while` loop then?

Comment: I doubt you need a loop, any time you're using a loop in SQL chances are you're not doing something set-based. Your operation is almost certainly possible using set-based symantics. See my answer.

Comment: @hermann: SQL works on sets of data that match particular condition. Not on individual row basis. It's like asking a group of people *all of you that are older than 20 and female, come with me*. You wouldn't be asking each individual of them but address the whole lot based on a condition. That's how SQL works. Women... ;)

Comment: What is that **something** that you want to do because it hugely depends on the data since it may be related to it or completely independent.

Comment: It is not related to the data. I just have to execute a chunk of code. Could be a SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Accumulating comparison results over the whole table

Checking that the whole table returns true for all rows is best done to count false ones and check whether that number is greater equal to 0. If it's 0 then it means that all rows matched otherwise number indicates number of rows that failed

Mind the **inverted** comparison compared to `Operator` value to catch negatives:

```
declare @NonMatched int

select
    @NonMatched = sum(
        case
            when [Operator] = '==' and Variable1 <> Variable2 then 1
            when [Operator] = '<>' and Variable1 = Variable2 then 1
            else 0
        end
    )
from @temp
where LinkingID = 1

if @NonMatched = 0
begin
    -- execute your stored procedure or whatever else set of statements
end
```

[Here's also a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d5bae/5) that's based on upper code.

Comment: @hermann: check my edited answer that counts number of those rows that fail comparison which in turn gives you information whether the whole table was a success or not. I think this is exactly what you're after.

Comment: I came back here to comment that it's not possible to have an ELSE statement for each separate WHEN, but you've already fixed it. Thank you. Comprehensive and works like a charm.

Comment: @hermann: Sorry had to change `count` to `sum`. Stupid mistake... :)

Answer (score 1):

Im going to go out on a limb and guess you're trying to do *something* with all rows which the conditional `variable 1 [operator] variable2` evaluates true. This could be selecting them, or deleting them - it makes no difference really.

I'll use a select as the example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM @temp
WHERE LinkingID = 1
AND CASE Operator
    WHEN '==' THEN Variable1 = Variable2
    WHEN '<>' THEN Variable1 <> Variable2
END
```

The same where clause could be used if you wanted to delete these records.

**EDIT** To aggregate up this set and do something when all conditions for a particular `LinkingID` evaluate true, something like this will work:

```
IF EXISTS(
  SELECT LinkingID FROM temp
  WHERE LinkingID = 1
  GROUP BY LinkingId
  HAVING SUM(CASE 
    WHEN Operator = '==' AND Variable1 = Variable2 THEN 1 
    WHEN Operator = '<>' AND Variable1 <> Variable2  THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END) = count(*)
)
BEGIN
  -- Do something
END
```

Live example to play with here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26d72/6
In that example I have set up LinkingID=2 where all conditions are true. Change the `LinkingId=1` to `=2` to see the `do something` message.

Comment: Dont see any difference, my answer would still be the same.

Comment: @hermann: your `case` statement logic doesn't need explicit true/false values. They're intrinsically gotten from actual comparison `var1 op var2` which is either `true` or `false`. No need to explicitly say the same...

Comment: if ALL rows for that Linking ID return true for their Variable1 `OPERATOR` Variable2, then do something. All `conditions` must return true.

Comment: @Jamiec thanks. You helped me correct my question and fix my logic as it was wrong when I first posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
           ( SELECT *
             FROM @temp
             WHERE LinkingID = 1
               AND NOT ( Operator = '=='  AND  Variable1 = Variable2
                      OR Operator = '<>'  AND  Variable1  <> Variable2
                       )
           ) THEN 'TRUE' 
             ELSE 'FALSE'
     END AS Result ;
```